# New to jquery. How to combine these scripts?

Tags: jquery

I want some buttons to filter the different cpts on a click using the data target attribute. So the button gets `data-target="logos"` for example and a click will show only that type. I am using the below script and it works great.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.buttons-two a').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        var target =  jQuery(this).data('target');
        if (target === 'all') {
            jQuery('.status-publish').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.status-publish').hide();
            jQuery('.type-' + target).show();
        } 
    });
});
```

The problem is that I also want to filter by tag. So an item with the tag "spotlight" will show on a button click calling that data target. To get this to work I changed the last line above to `jQuery('.tag-' + target).show();` and this works, but only when I use it in a separate script.

What would be the proper way to combine these two scripts?

Here are the two sets of buttons (only way I can get it to work):

```
<div class="buttons-two">
  <a class="btn btn-default showSingle" data-target="portfolio-spotlight">Spotlight</a>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <a class="btn btn-default showSingle" data-target="brochures">Brochures</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default showSingle" data-target="business-cards">Business Cards</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default showSingle" data-target="logos">Logos</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default showSingle" data-target="misc">Misc</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default showSingle" data-target="postcards">Postcards</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default showSingle" data-target="stationery">Stationery</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default showSingle" data-target="websites">Websites</a>
</div>
```

Edit:

So it does work now, but I have no idea why. Here is the script that is currently on the page:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.buttons-two a').click(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        var target = jQuery(this).data('target');
        if (target === 'all') {
            jQuery('.status-publish').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('.status-publish').hide();
            jQuery('.tag-' + target).show();
            jQuery('.type-' + target).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Only buttons of the class `buttons-two` are now being referenced, but the script is working on both sets--class `buttons` as well. I'm happy that it works, but this makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Can you share a HTML sample code, please ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, just adding `jQuery('.tag-' + target).show();` after `jQuery('.type-' + target).show()` should work.

Comment: @Alvaro Flaño Larrondo: That's what I thought as well. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `console.log` a few things to try and pin point where it gets to because I would of thought @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo 's solution would of worked too

Comment: Can you share also a sample of the content to show/hide, please ?

Comment: Just tried it again to confirm and it did work this time. Not sure what I did differently last time. Sigh. Thanks guys.

Comment: Just a note since you said you're new to jQuery. Most code you find will use `$` instead of `jQuery`. This is because it makes your JavaScript smaller. The main reason you'll see `jQuery` is if they have code where `$` is already defined as something else.

Comment: @dman2306: Thanks. The original script had `$`. I had to change it to make it work. Any idea on why clicks on `class="buttons"` are working when that is no longer being referenced in the script. Completely stumped on that.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache? If it's doing things that aren't in the code after you changed it, it sounds like there is a caching issue.

Comment: @dman2306: Yes, I've cleared my cache and checked it in several different browsers. My understanding was that `jQuery('.buttons-two a').click(function()` was saying a click event on `class="buttons-two"`, but it is also working on `class="buttons"` even though that is no longer in the script.